# Google Play app rejected, Issue found, Invalid Data safety form, What is the solution?

Tags: android, sdk, google-play, google-play-console

My app update on the google play store is rejected and I got this mail from the google play store :
after that I have update and submit 2 steps in Data safety form, "Location" and "Device or other IDs"!

can any one please tell me if there is any other things i need to do?
also after submit new update data safety form, how much time google play took to send me mail regarding my app status publish or rejected etc...

Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 2: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Location Data Type - Precise Location, Possible SDKs: com.intentsoftware.addapptr.subsdk:AdColony

SPLIT_BUNDLE 2: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address), Possible SDKs: com.adcolony:sdk, com.admost.sdk:adcolony, com.iqzone.thirdparty:adcolony

Note: My app is like tiktok type there is feature same type of feature like browse video, upload video, video streaming, showing ads, login through mobile number,email,google,facebook  also buy coins

Please suggest a solution so that the app can be updated on the google play store.

i am looking for solution of my issue above mention

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic